# How do I get Timeline data from Glimpse for reporting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I am using Glimpse with MVC4, I would like to capture timeline tab data of Glimpse and store it in a DB or File for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but I'll provide you with the answer that gives you the highest level of granularity, which has also been [covered on Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx).

Hanselman shows how to create the following `IInspector` implementation:

```
using Glimpse.Core.Extensibility;
using Glimpse.Core.Message;

public class TimelineTracer : IInspector
{
    public void Setup(IInspectorContext context) {
        context.MessageBroker.Subscribe<ITimelineMessage>(TraceMessage);
    }

    private void TraceMessage(ITimelineMessage message) {
        var output = string.Format(
            "{0} - {1} ms from beginning of request. Took {2} ms to execute.",
            message.EventName,
            message.Offset.Milliseconds,
            message.Duration.Milliseconds);

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(output, message.EventCategory.Name);
    }
}
```

If you add this class to your solution, it will be auto-discovered by Glimpse and the `TraceMessage` method will be called every time a record is added to the Glimpse Timeline.

Scott simply traces that information out, to be seen in the Azure Streaming Diagnostics service. You could instead save the data to a database (or something) to do the analysis you'd like later.